# How to shoot a character from one platform to another. (BGE)

Tags: game-engine, physics

So my character (character physics) will be traveling through the level and I want him to be able to jump into a cannon of sorts, and when a button is pushed, he gets fired upwards along a parabolic path to another platform to make the level more interesting. I've tried making an invisible platform that carries him quickly, but it doesn't work and is really hard to make anyway. I am obviously new to blender, so it feels like there is a very simple solution that I'm just not finding.... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final result:

[image]

**What's happening**

So I have a player, a floor for the player to walk on, a wall to jump over, and a cannon to launch him.

The player has a basic setup:
[image]

`W` to move forward, `A` to turn left, `S` to move backward, and so on.
The motion of the Dynamic player is simply the Location of the Motion Actuator.
(You probably have a different setup)

Now, inside the `cannon`, I added a child cube, that I'm calling `inside`. It's static and has the `cannon` as a parent. It's also Invisible and has the Ghost property applied.

[image]

**The logic bricks**

Referencing the above image, when the `player` comes into contact with the `inside` cube, the keyboard sensors will activate. When `A` is pressed, they will activate the cannon's Motion Actuator, that will turn the `cannon` `2` degrees along the Global Z axis. Likewise, when `D` is pressed, it will move `-2` degrees.

Last of all, when the `Spacebar` is pressed while in contact with the `inside` cube, the `Player`'s Motion Actuator is triggered with a force of `800` along the Z axis. Because the `cannon` is slanted, the player will hit the top of the `cannon` and will be forced out of the `cannon` at the same angle. This will not work if your cannon is vertical.

**Here is the .blend file:**

[image]

Comment: I will definitely use this. Do you have any idea how to make it so that the cannon will automatically aim and shoot the character so that it lands in a specific spot? I'm gonna need something like that as well. This is pretty great though. ;)

Comment: Create an animation for the cannon when the `inside` is in contact with the player, so the animation will play and the cannon will move automatically to your desired location.

Comment: Oh.... duh. I should have thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: I got it to work until I tried it with my character. It's collision cube has character physics, so its motion controls are different and I don't see any "force" option. Any ideas?

Comment: The character physics does not have the force, you'll have to either make your character dynamic or parent your character to an invisible cube that's dynamic.

Comment: Aha. I figured out a way to do it. Not exactly that way, but it works now. Thanks.